# AddEventListener not working with onClick

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

I am trying to use windows.addEventListener to execute my function on clicking a div. However nothing is happening.

This is my code:

Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

function init(){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById("wheelContainer").addEventListener("onclick", function() { winPrize;
        }, false);
    });
}
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least three things wrong here:

1. The event name for use with `addEventLisener()` is `"click"`, not `"onclick"`.
2. You should use the window `load` event OR the `DOMContentLoaded` event, but not both.
3. Your click handler function isn't actually doing anything.  Did you mean to call a function like `winPrize();`?

So, cleaning all of those issues, you would have this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("wheelContainer").addEventListener("click", function() { winPrize();
    }, false);
});
```

You don't need the `init()` function or the window load event handler at all since you can just install the event handler when the `DOMContendLoaded` event fires.

Comment: *"onclick"* would be used for `attachEvent` for legacy IE support. I want to upvote this answer, but daily limit reached :(

Comment: So If I remove the windows load event and just have the Document add event listener event it should work?:

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("clickToPlay").addEventListener("click", function() { winPrize;
  }, false);
 });

Comment: @NiraliPatel - yes, that should work as I've added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I have edited my code as above and its still not working. I have tried it in IE11 and Firefox26.0. When I added the function directly to the windows event (did not bind it to any element) it worked correctly. I am not sure how to fix this :|

Comment: @NiraliPatel - the other thing I noticed is that your click event handler isn't actually doing anything.  You just have `winPrize;` in the event handler, but that doesn't do anything.  Did you mean to make it a function call like `winPrize();`?

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yes Thankyou! I did mean to make it a function call!! It works now.